# Validate all or none text fields in Kendo & dynamically remove messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

For the code below it looks for an empty field in the 4 required fields if the user enters the address/city/state/zip field. Then it loops to check if any of them are empty. If all 4 are empty, then validation passes. If All of them contain data, then it should pass. The only time it should fail is if 1-3 of them are empty.

```
var validator = $("#AddressInfoForm").kendoValidator(
    {
        rules: {
            PayeeRequired: function (input) {
                if (input.is("[name=Address]") || input.is("[name=City]") || input.is("[name=State]") || input.is("[name=Zip]")) {
                    var fieldsBlank = 0;
                    var requiredFields = ["Address", "City", "State", "Zip"];
                        for (var i = 0; i < requiredFields.length; i++) {
                            var val = $('#' + requiredFields[i]);
                            if (val.val() == "") {
                                fieldsBlank += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    if (fieldsBlank > 0 && fieldsBlank < 4 && input.val() == "")
                        input.addClass("inputfields-validation-error");
                        fieldsBlank = 0;
                        return false;
                    }
                    input.removeClass("inputfields-validation-error");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        },
    }
).data("kendoValidator");
```

The issue I'm having with this is that...

1. The previous validation messages do not disappear. They only disappear once I click into each input box. It *should* be checking dynamically across the board since all 4 fields are linked. This means if 3 fields are empty except one, then there should be errors for those 3 fields. Once I clear the 4th field, then all of those errors should hide. Unfortunately it only hides for the last field that I input into and then I need to individually click into each field.

Working code expectant...

Overall I am looking for improve/correct my code so that

Show the error message for the blank fields when more than zero and less than 4 are blank.

Dynamically update so that when I clear all the fields, it clears all the error messages. When I fill one, then the other 3 blank fields display errors.

No errors when all 4 are filled.

edit--------

utilizing

```
$("#Address, #City, #State, #Zip").on("change", function () {
    isModified = true;
    validator.validate();
});
```

Seems to work how I want; however, validator.validate() sets off the validation errors for all the other fields in my form. I only want the validation set off for the 4 fields Address, City, State, and Zip. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Address, #City, #State, #Zip").on("change", function () {
    validator.validateInput($("input[name=Address]"));
    validator.validateInput($("input[name=City]"));
    validator.validateInput($("input[name=State]"));
    validator.validateInput($("input[name=Zip]"));
});
```

Seems to work well. Let me know if there's a better way to do this!